# Power Sums over Ring Subset

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, finite-fields

Recently I discovered that given a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q = p^m$ and $H \leq \mathbb{F}_q$ an affine subspace then $\sum_{a \in H} a^n = 0$ for all $n < |H|-2$. This sounds like an intereseting property and I was curious to see if there is any analogous result over ring.

To be more specific I'm intereseted in the case where $R$ is Galois Ring, defined as $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}[x]/f(x)$ with $f(x)$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This ring have many properties in common with its residue field $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ one of which is the existence of sets $E \subseteq R$ (called exceptional) over which it is possibile to interpolate polynomials.
My question is if there exists any known construction/result about exceptional sets that satisfies the property $\sum_{a \in E} a^n = 0$ for all $n \leq |E| - 2$

Comment: Can you give a precise description of the set $E$, please? My candidate for $E$ would be the set of so called Teichmüller elements. It is closed under multiplication and in a bijective correspondence with $\Bbb{F}_q$. If we use Witt vectors of length $k$ and entries from $\Bbb{F}_q$ the Teichmüller elements are those Witt vectors whose only non-zero component is at position zero.

Comment: For $E$ to be exceptional the only condition required is that the projection $\pi : R \to R/pR \cong \mathbb{F}_q$ restricted on $E$ is injective. I agree that through Hensel Lemma we obtain an $E$ closed under multiplication (this can be done at least for $|E|$ prime that divides $q - 1$ lifting the generator) - however i don't think this is enough to give the desired property.

However with this construction $E = \{0, \alpha, \alpha^2, ..., \alpha^{|E| - 1}\}$ with $\alpha^{|E| - 1} = 1$ and $|E| - 1$ prime. It is therefore enough to check that $\sum E = 0$

Comment: The Teichmüller set $T$ is a (multiplicative) copy of ALL of $\Bbb{F}_q$. Obviously not every set projecting to the field injectively is closed under multiplication. In fact, I thought that the question was only about the inverse images of affine subsets $H$ of $\Bbb{F}_q$ in $T$, like $\pi^{-1}(H)\cap T$. Even this is asking too much though. I have a counterexample like that, and suspect that there are plenty. After all, unless you have that affine structure in $\pi(E)$ there is no reason to expect the same property to hold. If it is not true after $\pi$, it cannot be true before $\pi$.